# How to insert different values to a particular list from a different list

Tags: python

I have a list

```
a = [[1,2,3],[3,4,5]]
```

In every row at the end I want to insert values from a different list

```
b=[6,7]
```

I want the results to be

```
[[1,2,3,6],[3,4,5,7]]
```

I am using:

```
for i in range (0,len(a)):
    for j in range (0,len(b)):
        if j==0:
            a[i].append(b[j])
            m.append(a[i])
        else:
            a[i][3]=b[j]
            m.append(a[i])
        print m
```

But I am not getting the expected results. This gives me:

```
[[1, 2, 3, 7], [1, 2, 3, 7], [3, 4, 5, 7], [3, 4, 5, 7]]
```

Could someone help me out with the correct code snippet.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. You've asked a very good question that includes everything that is necessary: A clear problem description, sample input date, expected output, actual output, and the code you have tried. Many others asking their first question look at yours as an example for how to ask.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `zip`

**Ex:**

```
a=[[1,2,3],[3,4,5]]
b=[6,7]

for i, j in zip(a,b):
    i.append(j)
print(a)
```

**Output:**

```
[[1, 2, 3, 6], [3, 4, 5, 7]]
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But for simple implementation its works.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But in my code, when I do this append, then its appending 6,7 to every a . I mean I get the answer as [[1,2,3,6,7],[3,4,5,6,7]].can you help!

Answer (score 2):

Here is a solution using zip:

```
result = [sublist_a + [el_b] for sublist_a, el_b in zip(a, b)]
```

which gives the expected output:

```
[[1, 2, 3, 6], [3, 4, 5, 7]]
```